# prev/next of a sibling

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeTab = $('#tabs menu.active');
    var prevTab = activeTab.closest('.menu').prev();
    var nextTab = activeTab.closest('.menu').next();
    prevTab.addClass('prev');
    nextTab.addClass('next');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qS4LN/

It doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong? I need to addClass `prev` and `next` to the tabs around the `active` tab.

Comment: you miss a point on this line: $('#tabs menu.active'); menu is a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the first period on your selector.  Your code is:

```
var activeTab = $('#tabs menu.active');
```

menu is a class and needs it's own period.  Change the code to:

```
var activeTab = $('#tabs .menu.active');
```

Answer (score 1):

updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qS4LN/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeTab = $('#tabs ul.menu.active');
    var prevTab = activeTab.closest('.menu').prev();
    var nextTab = activeTab.closest('.menu').next();
    prevTab.addClass('prev');
    nextTab.addClass('next');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot on 2nd line selector, change var activeTab = $('#tabs menu.active'); to var activeTab = $('#tabs ul.menu.active');